# Authenticate from onelogin and redirect to dashboard

Tags: node.js, reactjs, passport.js, onelogin

I have an app with react/redux frontend and express backend which I created using `create-react-app`. I want to do authentication using onelogin and passportjs. Following this guide (https://developers.onelogin.com/quickstart/authentication/nodejs) I was able to setup everything, the issue is, my express server is running on port 5000, but the react app runs on port 3000.

If I go to `localhost:3000/login`, nothing happens, and If I go to `localhost:5000/login` I do get authenticated with onelogin, but nothing is ever returned, and it just gets stuck.

This is my `/login` code

```
app.get('/login', passport.authenticate('openidconnect', {
    successReturnToOrRedirect: "/",
    scope: 'profile',
}));
```

And this is the callback

```
app.get('/oauth/callback', passport.authenticate('openidconnect', {
    callback: true,
    successReturnToOrRedirect: '/',
    failureRedirect: '/login'
}));
```

Here's the full code (https://github.com/onelogin/onelogin-oidc-node/blob/master/1.%20Auth%20Flow/app.js)

I understand why this is all happening, since my express server doesn't render anything. But how can I handle this?

Answer (score 0):

Redirecting to `localhost:3000/create` instead of `/create` fixed it. Not sure if best practice.

```
app.get('/login', passport.authenticate('openidconnect', {
    successReturnToOrRedirect: "localhost:3000/create",
    scope: 'profile',
}));

app.get('/oauth/callback', passport.authenticate('openidconnect', {
    callback: true,
    successReturnToOrRedirect: 'http://localhost:3000/create',
    failureRedirect: 'http://localhost:3000/login'
}));
```

Comment: This is an interesting alternative I will definitely look into passport in the future. Only issue I see with this authentication method is how do you determine if a user is authenticated if no token/cookies is stored on the client. for example what happens if a user refreshes /create how do you know if this is a new user or the same user?

Answer (score 0):

you have to proxy your request to the backend add this line to your packages.json

```
"proxy": "http://127.0.0.1:5000/"
```

how are you making your request to authenticate from the front end? when doing authentication with react I use react-router and then use `axios` to authenticate

so when user submits the login form I make a post request to the login route to return a JWT (I have not used passport before). All future requests from the client I include the jwt to validate the user as authenticated.

```js
    import Cookies from "js-cookie";
    import QueryString from "query-string";
    import axios from 'axios';
    
    let myUrl =  "login/";
    let myData = QueryString.stringify({
        ...this.state.form, 
    });


    axios.post(myUrl, myData,{
      headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8",
        "cache-control": "no-cache",
      },
    })
    .then((response) => {
      // store token in cookies
      // redirect to authenticated route
      Cookies.set('token', response.data.token,  { expires: 1/24 }) 
     })
    .catch((error) => {
      //handle displaying error to user here
     })
```

**if you are not using react router or are trying to serve data from your backend as apposed to retrieving it from the frontend please let me know and I will change my post to fit your authentication flow**